# What process is required to get the Help Center text changed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Recently, I voted to close this question [Can anybody understand what she's saying?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316579/can-anybody-understand-what-shes-saying) (it was subsequently deleted by the original poster) based on the answers to this Meta question: [Exactly WHY is this question Off Topic? Or not?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/exactly-why-is-this-question-off-topic-or-not)

However, I felt uncomfortable doing so, because despite some suggestions in these answers for adding this as an off-topic reason to the Help Center, this has never actually been done.

Because of this, I was thinking of posting a new Meta question that explicitly proposes adding this information to the Help Center.

But then I saw this question from 2015: [Informing people about lyrics interpretation in help center](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6886/informing-people-about-lyrics-interpretation-in-help-center)

This is basically the kind of post I was going to make. It received what I would consider a fair amount of support: 7 upvotes and no downvotes. It seems like nobody voiced any objections. But ultimately, it never led to anything. Our Help Center page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) still doesn't say anything about lyrics, as far as I can see.

What happened? Was the question just overlooked? Is there some other action that would be more effective in getting this kind of change accomplished?
Or was posting the proposal as a Meta question the right thing to do, and it's just that big changes like this require even more upvotes before a moderator will implement them?

Comment: A Meta discussion is all it takes, and if there's consensus, then they don't even necessarily need to be massively upvoted. The mods probably just needed a reminder about the lyric interpretation request.